# How to escape 'And' operator in thyeamleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have next thymeleaf code:

```
<select class="custom-select" th:field="*{...}">
  <option th:value="Given" th:text="Given">Given</option>
  <option th:value="When" th:text="When" selected>When</option>
  <option th:value="And" th:text="And">And</option>
  <option th:value="Then" th:text="Then">Then</option>
</select>
```

'And' is boolean operator in theamleaf and using it like that throws en error "Could not parse as expression".
I tried ascii characters but result is same.
Also tried use Russian A character instead of latin but this won't work for me because I will generate .feature file from this input and Russian characters doesn't recognized by cucumber.

So anyone know how to escape operator in thymeleaf?
The only way I see now it's use Russian character and then replace it in Runtime with latin A, but this looks overcomplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<option th:value="'And'" th:text="'And'">And</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, no need to use `th:` attributes.  Why not just use normal html?

```
<select class="custom-select" th:field="*{...}">
  <option value="Given" text="Given">Given</option>
  <option value="When" text="When" selected>When</option>
  <option value="And" text="And">And</option>
  <option value="Then" text="Then">Then</option>
</select>
```

As for escaping, there are a few ways if you really want that:

```
<!-- String escape -->
<option th:value="'And'" th:text="'And'">And</option>
<!-- Thymeleaf expression -->
<option th:value="${'And'}" th:text="${'And'}">And</option>
<!-- Literal substitution -->
<option th:value="|And|" th:text="|And|">And</option>
```